# Display a warning if characters on EditText don't meet the required length

Tags: android, android-edittext, content-length

How can I display a warning if user don't put required number of characters on an EditText?

Let's say the maxLength is 17 and user put 15 characters, how to warn them and/or perform some actions​ (e.g. disable the positive button, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: during button click check the validity condition

```
 button_submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //etNumber is your Edittext
            if (etNumber.getText().toString().trim().length() != 17) {
            //required length
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Number not valid", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            etNumber.requestFocus();
            }
        }
    });
```

**Option 2**

you can use [TextWatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) to check the condition during runtime.

Comment: This seems a simple. Trying. Thanks

Comment: or you can do onFocusOut too

Comment: @rafsanahmad007, why getApplicationContext gives "cannot resolve" error ?

Comment: if you are in fragment you need to use 'getActivity()' instead

Answer (score 1):

you can use a textChangeListener:

```
EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.my_edit_text);
et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int     after) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    //check the Strings length here and display warning
}
```

});

yoy can check the lenth of the string in the onTextChanged() method and than triger the desired action.

good luck

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

Add a TextWatcher to the EditText and if the user has filled less than the minimum amount, show an error with setError of android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText that should be inside a android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout

But with this approach you will be prompting the user as the user is filling the Edit.

My suggestion is to validate only when the user click the OK button, this way you don't show some kind of error and bother the user.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Trying now